# Flex only for two out of three elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have 3 seperate elements all in one container/wrapper.
I have flex applied so the image and Text are side by side. However i want the "Scroll Down" div to be placed underneath the other two elements while still using Flex.
Is there any flex property to somehow only apply Flex on the two first elements?

**Image:**
https://gyazo.com/a391508e26aff2486103579134c051e1

```
<section class="home-section">
            <div class="home-wrapper">
                <div class="home-column">
                <div class="home-row">
                    <h1>Centuries Gaming</h1>
                    <h2>Roleplay on a different level</h2>
                    <p>From the aspirations and dreams of others, we stand tall, proud, and loyal
                        to our visions and project. We provide the best and most immersive...</p>
                    <div class="home-buttons">
                        <div class="home-button home-button-left">
                            <a href="https://form.jotform.com/202344710763046">Apply</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="home-button home-button-right">
                            <a href="#about">Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="home-row">
                    <div class="home-image">
                        <img src="images/home-image.png" alt="Vehicle Drifting">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="home-scroll">
                <button>
                    <span>Scroll Down</span>
                    <img src="icons/mouse.svg" alt="Mouse Scroll Icon">
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

```
/* Home Section */

.home-section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-column {
  display: flex;
}

.home-row h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 7x;
}

.home-row h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff80;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home-row p {
  color: #ffffff80;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width:600px;
}

.home-row .home-buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider CSS Grid. Why? Flex is designed to help laying out a _single_ column or a _single_ row. Grid is designed to align _multiple_ columns and rows for which layout is related.

Comment: With that said, you'll need to encapsulate the scroll control inside another container that is displayed as flex.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `flex-direction: column;` to .home-section then the parent element will display its children vertically. And the scroll element will be below the order elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flex-direction:column**

```
.home-section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

The default is row, but you can change that property to stack the elements vertically. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction